# How can I write unit tests for C++ code that uses libssl fucntionality

Tags: c++, unit-testing, sockets, openssl, mocking

I have been working on updating a C++ TCP Server application that uses raw sockets to employ TLS via OpenSSL (libssl, libcrypto).

I have reached a point where I have tested the server application with a test client app and also with our customer's running software and the connection/sending/receiving seems to be working smoothly so far.

We would like to add unit tests to cover the various functionalities that deal with the context creation / SSL_accept() / SSL_read() / SSL_write() functions, but I am having trouble understanding how to do this.

I am hoping someone with more experience could help me understand how I could fake an SSL object or fake a peer presented certificate.. (or simulate a SSL connection in a unit test). I am thinking I may be able to do this by using an underlying BIO but I am having trouble finding the right example C++ code to base myself on.

Sorry if my question has poor style, it's my first question! :)